# Pandas adding previous row and current row into current row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame which is around 100x100 and I want to add previous cell + current cell = current cell

An example of the Data Frame:

```
User     A     B    C   D  
Apple    0     5    6   4 
Orange   23    0    3   5 
Grape    5     10   9   6 
Fruit    67    3    0   9
```

The desired output:

```
User     A     B    C   D  
Apple    0     5    11  15 
Orange   23    23   26  31 
Grape    5     15   24  30 
Fruit    67    70   70  79
```

Using Pandas is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation is called cumulative sum:

```
df.cumsum(axis=1)
```

(I assume that "User" is the index).